# mysqli_query vacio

Tags: php, javascript

tengo el siguiente problema al realizar un mysqli_query. Cuando lo realizo con una variable en la sentencia SQL me devuelve 0 registros, pero si cambio la variable por un registro de la tabla si que me funciona. adjunto el código. (No da ningún tipo de error)

var variableJS = params['codigo'];

```
    $codigo ="<script> document.write(variableJS) </script>";
    $sql = "SELECT * from material where codigo = '" . $codigo ."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
        echo $row[0].$row[1].$row[2].$row[3].$row[4];

        $option = $row[0];
        $codigo = $option;
        $option = substr($option,0,1); 
        $nombre = $row[1];
        $pcte = $row[2];
        $pvp = $row[3];
        $stock = $row[4];
        if ($option == "P")
            {
                $option = 1;
        }else
                {
                    $option = 2;

            }

                }       
?>
```

Bueno ya tengo claro que el problema es el valor de $codigo, que no entiendo por que al realizar el var_dump me dice string(45) "P-001". El código es correcto lo que no es correcto es string(45) cuando debería ser string (5). Alguien sabe a que puede ser debido?
El $codigo lo recibo desde otra página.php con window.location.search.substr(1);

Al fin he conseguido dar con la tecla. El final estaba recogiendo mal la variable de la url. Esta es la forma correcta: $codigo = $_GET['codigo'];
Yo lo estaba haciendo con una función que había copiado de internet que no me daba el resultado deseado. Muchas gracias a todos.

Comment: Ya probo si la variable `$codigo ` esta obteniendo algun valor ?

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar. $codigo tiene el valor que necesito. Pero no me realiza la consulta, sin embargo poniendo ese valor directamente si. Es algo que me trae de cabeza.

Comment: has un select normal sin where, solo para probar si el error no esta en la conexcion a la bd

Comment: Muchas gracias, comprobado que la conexiona  la bd es correcta.

Answer (score 0):

intenta usar el

```
var_dump($codigo);
```

el var_dump es una función muestra información estructurada sobre una o más expresiones incluyendo su tipo y valor, te sirve para ver el valor de esa variable, si $codigo te sale NULL es que esta vació por eso no puede hacer la consulta

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar. he realizado el var_dump y el resultado es el esperado creo: /volume1/web/ProductoModificar.php:178: string(45) "P-001" que es el código del Producto que busco.

Comment: Por cierto, no entiendo esto: string(45) "P-001" cuando debería ser string(5) "P-001".

Answer (score 0):

Hazle un `trim()` a `$codigo`, ya que posiblemente tenga espcios en blanco, seria algo asi:

```
$codigo ="<script> document.write(variableJS) </script>";
$codigo = trim($codigo);
$sql = "SELECT * from material where codigo = '$codigo'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());
```

te recomiendo que empieces a implementar sentencias preparadas para evitar problemas de injeccion:

espero te soluciones, me cuentas!

Comment: Muchas gracias por el consejo. Lo he intentado pero no funciona sigue el mismo problema. Lo que no entiendo es que hago un echo $codigo y me imprime P-001 correctamente, pero luego no hace la consulta. Tiene que ver seguramente con el parametro string(45), porque si pongo $codigo = 'P-001' me realiza la consulta sin problema y al hacer el var_dump de $codigo asi me sale string(5).

Comment: mi siguiente paso sin duda es implementar sentencias preparadas, pero este paso me trae de cabeza.